# Rails - How to accomplish duplicate Log In fields based on responsive design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

So, one thing I know is that setting two different IDs in the same page is **BAD NEWS**.

The way that I have it established is I'm using a responsive framework (Foundation 5) to have two separate log in fields that are either `hidden` or `visible` depending on your browser resolution. I don't want to establish two different pages in the event of a `window.resize` event.

So, if I happen to have:

```
<div class="show-for-small">
  <li><input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email address" /></li>
  <li><input id="password" type="text" placeholder="password" /></li>
</div>
```

And:

```
<div class="show-for-medium-up">
  <li><input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email address" /></li>
  <li><input id="password" type="text" placeholder="password" /></li>
</div>
```

Am I able to use this sort of logic in *Rails* as long as one is **always** hidden, or should I use some logical operator to assess which is viewable before I apply the log in method to the documents (probably applying classes instead within erb)?

Comment: I'm sure someone's going to ask why you need two forms, so instead I'm gonna ask why you need to use id attributes?

Comment: Why can't use use media queries for styling and just have one form?

Comment: Well, regarding the ID attributes Foundation 5 has some hideous out of the box input fields and setting an ID to the form was the easiest way to override them. As far as media queries, they are in two TOTALLY different locations with two TOTALLY different styles (the mobile one actually slides in from the side but the desktop version is static).